# How to join or include checkbox array from datatable with form values in ajax

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, join, serialization

I'm needing help figuring out how to join an array of selected checkbox values with input data from a form. I am getting the selected values from selected checkboxes on a data table and using a form to create the new values.  Next, I want to join the entered form values to each of the already selected values from the checkbox array so that I can use ajax to create a query with the joined data.  Maybe an alternative solution could be to not join the data but include it as separate data in the ajax? (which I also do not know how to do)  I just started learning to code about a month ago will someone please point me in the right direction.  Thanks!

### this is the part I need help with

```
    $(document).on("click", '#btn-draft', function() {
    var user = [];
    $(".user_checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        user.push($(this).data('user-id'));
    });
    if(user.length <=0) {
        alert("Please select records."); 
    } 
    else { 
            
            var selected_values = user.join(",");
            var form_values = $("#draft_form").serialize();
            var all_values = ??? // idk what to do here?

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "backend/save.php",
                cache:false,
                data:{
                    type: 6,                        
                    id : all_values, 
                    

                },
                success: function(response) {
                    var ids = response.split(",");
                    
                    for (var i=0; i < ids.length; i++ ) {   
                        $( "#myTable" ).load( "index.php #myTable" );

                    }   
                } 
            }); 
          
    } 
});
});
```

### html

```
<body>

<main class='main-content'>


<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div ng-app='ui.bootstrap.demo'>


  <!-- DROPDOWNS -->
  <div ng-controller='DropdownCtrl'>
                                                                                                    
    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="row">
            </div>
            <div class="row">           

                                <!-- Split button -->
                <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#add-Options" data-toggle='modal'>Add New</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id='draft_multiple'>Create Draft Class</a></li>
                                                                                                                                
                    </ul>
                </div>
        <!--datatable HTML -->

            <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id='myTable'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
                                <label for="selectAll"></label>
                            </span>
                        </th>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>BD</th>
                        <th>BA</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                
                <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM properties");
                    $i=1;
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>
                <tr id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
                <td>
                            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="user_checkbox" data-user-id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
                                <label for="checkbox2"></label>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["address"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["BD"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["BA"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["city"]; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $i++;
                }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <!-- Modal HTML -->
        <div id="draftModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <form id='draft_form'>

      <div class="modal-body">
          <span>
New Draft <br/> Class</span>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
      <p>
       <input type="text" placeholder="" id='myInput' name='myInput'>
      </p>
   
  </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
      <input type="hidden" value="6" name="type">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-draft" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Save</a>
      </div>
        </form>


</body>
```

### main script (full)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        var checkbox = $('table tbody input[class="user_checkbox"]');
        $("#selectAll").click(function(){
            if(this.checked){
                checkbox.each(function(){
                    this.checked = true;                        
                });
            } else{
                checkbox.each(function(){
                    this.checked = false;                        
                });
            } 
        });
        checkbox.click(function(){
            if(!this.checked){
                $("#selectAll").prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('#draft_multiple').on('click', function(){
        var id = [];
        
        $('.user_checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
            id[i] = $(this).val();      
        });
        
        if(id.length == 0){
            alert("Please select records."); 
            
        }else{
            $('#draftModal').modal("show");

            $.ajax({
                url: 'result.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {id: id},
                success: function(data){
                    $('#result').html(data);
                    
                }
            });
        }   
    });
    
    $(document).on("click", '#btn-draft', function() {
    var user = [];
    $(".user_checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        user.push($(this).data('user-id'));
    });
    if(user.length <=0) {
        alert("Please select records."); 
    } 
    else { 
            
            var selected_values = user.join(",");
            var form_values = $("#draft_form").serialize();
            var all_values= ??? //idk what to do here?
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "backend/save.php",
                cache:false,
                data:{
                    type: 6,                        
                    id : all_values, 
                    

                },
                success: function(response) {
                    var ids = response.split(",");
                    
                    for (var i=0; i < ids.length; i++ ) {   
                        $( "#myTable" ).load( "index.php #myTable" );

                    }   
                } 
            }); 
          
    } 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please follow the requirement for asking a question. At least provide your HTML.

Comment: @Reflective sorry I have a lot of code all in the html I tried my best to consolidate it.  I have updated the post with all the relevant parts of the code I'm using.  Thank you!